# count() in select field return always one row if no match found in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

count() in select fields, return always one row if no match found mysql with search criteria. But Count function returns 0 always as a result DB returns one records with null values.

Can some help me out of this situation.

I am sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Query:

```
SELECT  LastStatusMessageIDName
       ,COUNT(1) AS [Count of Total Records]
       ,COUNT(LastExecutionResult) AS [Count of Non-NULL Records]
       ,SUM(CASE WHEN LastExecutionResult IS NULL THEN 1 END) AS [Count of NULL Records]
  FROM dbo.v_ClientAdvertisementStatus
```

Hope this help ..!!

Comment: In my case Count is coming from a joined (child) table. When parent table matches no criteria even that query results one row because child table counts return 0

Comment: can you please share your query here?

Comment: Thanks Ankit for your help, i have added having clause on count of parent record id which solved my problem

Comment: glad to help you anytime :)